# Make Zeitgeist aware of downloaded files from Firefox/Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, zeitgeist

I'd like to make Zeitgiest aware of files I've downloaded from Chrome/Firefox.

Currently Zeitgeist only becomes aware of them once they've been opened in some other program.

This would be helpful for manipulating downloaded files in Synapse/Gnome activity Journal/"Recent Items" etc.

Comment: Not possible for now if I look at bugs file for ff and zeitgeist: current data source only logs pages visited. You could file a question on launchpad for this here: https://answers.launchpad.net/zeitgeist-project/+addquestion

Comment: Please [open a bug against Zeitgeist-datasources](https://bugs.launchpad.net/zeitgeist-dataproviders/+filebug) . It would be great to implement this